# With the pigeon hole principle how do you tell which are the pigeons and which are the holes?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

For example, I was reading this example from my textbook:

> Let S be a set of six positive integers who maximum is at most 14.
>   Show that the sums of the elements in all the nonempty subsets of S
>   cannot all be distinct.
>
> For each nonempty subset A of S the sum of the elements in A denoted
>   $$S_A$$ satisfies $$1\leq S_A \leq 9+10+...+14=69$$ and there are $$2^6-1=63$$
>   nonempty subsets of S. We should like to draw the conclusion from the
>   pigeonhole principle by letting the possible sums, from 1 to 69 be the
>   pigeonholes with 63 nonempty subsets of S as the pigeons but then we
>   have too few pigeons.

Why can't you say that there are 63 pigeonholes and 69 pigeons?

Comment: I'm reminded of a sicker statement of the piegonhole principle: if you have $n$ pigeons and put $k$ holes in them, where $k > n$, then at least one pigeon will have at least two holes in it.

Comment: To flesh out a comment by user [spd_25](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/621918/spd-25) posted as an answer. A more refined estimate for $S_A$ _would_ allow the use of the pigeonhole principle here: The sum is minimum for the subset $\{\min S\}$, and bounded above by $\min S + 10 + 11 + 12 + 13 + 14$, i.e. $\min S \leq S_A \leq 60 + \min S$, which allows us to consider only 61 pigeonholes instead. See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2888844. (Maybe the textbook does go on to explain this after the quoted part.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example you are putting the subsets of $S$ (which all have sums) and placing them into the sums of $1$ to $69$. Think of the sums of $S$ as bins, we only have $63$ non empty subsets, and $69$ bins to put them in.

Answer (score 1):

When you are asked to show that "There are at least two $X$ with the same $Y$, then $X$ are usually the pigeons and $Y$ are usually the holes.