# Let S be a set of six positive integers who maximum is at most 14.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $\mathcal S$ be a set of six positive integers who maximum is at most 14. Show that the sums of the elements in all the nonempty subsets of $\mathcal S$ cannot all be distinct

For each non-empty subset, $\mathcal A$ of $\mathcal S$ the sum of the elements in $\mathcal A$ denoted as $S_\mathcal A$ satisfies
$$1\leq S_\mathcal A \leq 9 + 10 + \cdots + 14 = 69$$
and there are $2^6−1=63$ non-empty subsets.

How do you know that the sums start from $9$ and goes to $14$? $(9+10+...+14= 69)$. Why can't it start from $1$?

Comment: No one is saying that the sum $SA$ is _equal_ to $9+10+\dots+14$. The proof you quoted is just saying that the sums is _at most_  $9+10+\dots+14=69$, that is that $69$ is the largest possible value of $SA$. Knowing the range of values $SA$ can take allows you to apply the pigeonhole principle.

Comment: if SA is not the sum then what is it and why does it start from 9?

Comment: Consider $S=\{1,3,5,7,9,11\}.$ It has six integers and the maximum is $11$ (so at most $14.$)

Comment: Maybe it's assumed that the integers are distinct? Then the maximum sum would indeed be $69$.

Comment: @John If two elements are the same, the subsets containing just the separate copies of those elements trivially have equal sums - so it need not be assumed in posing the question, provided it is dealt with in the answer.

Comment: or can we say that S={9,10,11,12,13,14} which in that case when you have itself as a subset, the sum is 69?

Comment: Right, it's a set, so the elements must be distinct. Duh.

Comment: @John that is not what i meant. what i dont understand is why do they only add 9-14?

Comment: @DimaSmith78 Those are the six distinct integers not greater than $14$ that create the maximum sum.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $S$ contains two equal elements. Then the subsets of $S$ comprising only these elements have equal sums, so the sums are not all distinct.

Now suppose $S$ does not contain two equal elements, i.e. the elements of $S$ are all distinct.

Let $x$ be the smallest element of $S$.

Then the smallest possible value of $S_A$ is $x$.

And the largest possible value of $S_A$ is $x+10+11+12+13+14=x+60$.

Since $x<S_A<x+60$, there are $61$ possible values of $S_A$.

And since there are $2^6-1=63$ non-empty subsets, these cannot all have distinct sums since there are only $61$ possible values available for the sum.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $\max S=12.$ Then the sum of the elements of any subset os $S$ is bounded from above by $$12+11+10+9+8+7=57.$$ Since there are $63$ non-empty subsets of $S$ there are two subsets which the sum of elements is the same.

Assume that $\max S=13.$ Then the sum of the elements os $S$ is bounded by $$13+12+11+10+9+8=63.$$ Since $13+8=12+9=11+10$ we get that if $S=\{8,9,10,11,12,13\}$ there are subsets of $S$ $(\{8,13\},\{9,12\},\{10,11\})$ whose elements sum the same. In other case $\max S=13$ and the sum of the elements of $S$ is $<63.$ Repeating the argument with the existenc of $63$ non-empty subsets we are done.

Assume $\max S=14.$ If $S=\{9,10,11,12,13,14\}$ we are done (because $10+13=11+12$). So the maximum of the sum is $68.$ Assume the worst scenario: $\{12,13,14\}\subset S.$ Then $11\notin S.$ (In other case $11+14=12+13$.) It could be $\{10,12,13,14\}\subset S.$ So $9\notin S$ because $13+9=10+12.$ For the same reason $8\notin S$ because $8+14=10+12.$ So the sum of the elements of $S$ is at most $$14+13+12+10+7+6=61.$$

Now assume $13\notin S.$ The the sum of the elements of $S$ is $64.$ The worst scnecario here is $\{10,11,12,14\}\subset S.$ For the same reason as above it is $9\notin S$ (in other case $9+12=10+11$.) So the sum of elements of $S$ is at most $7+8+10+11+12+14=64.$ But if $S=\{7,8,10,11,12,14\}$ then $7+11=10+8.$ So $7\notin S.$ In a similar way $S\ne \{6,8,10,11,12,14\}.$ So the sum of the elements of $S$ is $<63.$

Since the sum of the numbers of $s$ is smaller than the number of non-emptysets "Pingeonhole principle again".

Answer (score -1):

import Java.util.Scanner;
public static void main(String [] args){
Scanner userInput=new Scanner(System.in);
int numberOfPigeons=0;
int numberOfPigeonholes=0;
System.out.println("Please enter the number of pigeons: ");
numberOfPigeons=userInput.nextInt();
System.out.println("Please enter the number of pigeonholes: );
numberOfPigeonholes=userInput.nextInt();
if(checkValidity(numberOfPigeons,numberOfPigeonholes)==true)
System.out.println("The statement is correct");
else
System.err.println("The statement is not correct");

}
public static boolean checkValidity(int numberOfPigeons,int numberOfPigeonholes){
if(numberOfPigeons<=numberOfPigeonholes){
return false;
}
else
return true;
}

Comment: You may provide some mathematical statement not Java code